A norm identity
Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are two Banach spaces, then we know that for $A\in L(X,Y)$, i.e. a linear bounded mapping from $X$ to $Y$, we have
$$\|A\| = \sup_{x\in X, \|x\| \leq 1}\|Ax\|.$$
My question is do we have
$$\|x\| = \sup_{A\in L(X,Y), \|A\|\leq 1}\|Ax\|?$$
I can get one direction, namely
$$\|x\| \geq \sup_{A\in L(X,Y), \|A\|\leq 1}\|Ax\|,$$
because if $\|A\| \leq 1$, then $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\|\|x\| \leq \|x\|$.
For the other direction, what I can get is if $X=Y$, then we can choose $A$ to be identity and the equality is true.
But for genenral case when $Y\neq X$, is the reverse direction correct? And if so, how can we prove that?

Assuming we’re in the nontrivial case, i.e., $Y \neq \{0\}$, then yes. Indeed, by Hahn-Banach, there exists $\varphi \in X^\ast$ s.t. $\|\varphi\| = 1$ and $\varphi(x) = \|x\|$. Fix some $y \in Y$ with norm $1$. Then $A \in L(X, Y)$ defined by,
$$Ax = \varphi(x)y$$
has norm $1$, and $\|Ax\| = \|x\|$.
